# DataTables 1.10 column count

Tags: datatables-1.10

I want to add an additional `<thead>` that will contain my filters for that column in datatable.

I am able to do that using the following script. (For this to work I should have thead defined in dom)

```js
var tableid = $('#dataTableBuilder');
num_columns = tableid.find('thead > tr:first > th').length;
tableid.find('thead > tr:first').before('<tr id="filter-row"></tr>');
var filterrow = tableid.find('#filter-row');

while (num_columns-- > 0) filterrow.append('<th></th>');
```

Problem is I do not want to look at DOM to figure out number of columns to add those many `<th>`. (Reason for this is I am using Yajra Datatables HtmlBuilder to generate my table and I do not know number of columns upfront and the table code that this adds is only `<table id='xxxxxx'></table>`)

I hope the question is understood, I just need to know how can I get count of number of columns using datatables.

I tried `myDataTable.fnSettings().aoColumns.length` but it says "fnSettings is not a function" it looks like it is depricatedin 1.10, is there any alternative to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the 1.10.x API there is multiple ways to get the number of columns. Examples :

```js
var colCount = table.columns().header().length;
var colCount = table.row(0).data().length;
var colCount = table.columns()[0].length;
...
```

Regarding `myDataTable.fnSettings().aoColumns.length` I believe you are thinking of

`table.init().columns` / `table.init().aoColumns` etc

But `table.init()` only hold initialization options you actually have passed to dataTables. If you have a dataTables initialisation like this

```js
var table = $("#example").DataTable({
   columnDefs : [
     { targets : [0], sortable : false }
   ]
})
```

then `table.init().columnDefs` and `table.init().aoColumnDefs` will be present, but `table.init().columns` will not, since you have not passed a `columns` struct to dataTables.